# How can I register graphql for all modules separately like we register routes in Provider?

Tags: laravel, laravel-lighthouse

I have Laravel project with submodule I have to create graphql file in each module for a separate routes.

How can I register graphql for all modules separately like we register routes in Provider?
How to handle graphql file in multiple modules?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using includes. For example, in a project I'm working on, the graphql files are split up per entity. We import them like so:

```
#import ../Entities/*/*.graphqls
```

Note that the import is relative to the location of the schema file.

For more information see the [docs](https://lighthouse-php.com/4.8/digging-deeper/schema-organisation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just another way... I also have my code splitted by modules, I have something like this in my ServiceProvider:

```
public function __construct(Application $app)
    {
        parent::__construct($app);
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass($this);
        $this->folder = dirname($reflection->getFileName());
    }

public function bootGraphql()
    {
        $graphql = $this->folder.'/Graphql/module_schema.graphql';
        if (file_exists($graphql)) {
            Event::listen(BuildSchemaString::class, function () use ($graphql) {
                return (new SchemaStitcher($graphql))->getSchemaString();
            });
        }
    }
```

Then, in your `module_schema.graphql` you can also use the `#import */*.graphql`. So every `.graphql` file inside your `Graphql` folders are loaded.